# VBA Excel - Macro tells me Word Document is Open even though it is not open

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, macros

To start off I have a function in VBA Excel that tells me if a Word Document is open or not open. For testing purposes I don't have the Word Document Open and expect 'False' to be returned.

```
Function IsFileOpen(filename As String) As Boolean
        Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

        On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
        filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
        ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
        Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum
        Close filenum          ' Close the file.
        errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
        On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

        ' Check to see which error occurred.
        Select Case errnum

            ' No error occurred.
            ' File is NOT already open by another user.
            Case 0
             IsFileOpen = False

            ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
            ' File is already opened by another user.
            Case 70
                IsFileOpen = True

            ' Another error occurred.
            Case Else
                Error errnum
        End Select

    End Function
```

Called Via:

```
...
If IsFileOpen("C:/Temp/test.docx") = True Then
 MsgBox objWord.ActiveDocument.Name & " already open" 'ERROR FROM PIC HERE
 Set objDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument
Else
 Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:/Temp/test.docx", Visible:=True)
End If
...
```

However when running the code I get that the Document is open (Returned True from the IsFileOpen function from case 70) yet I get an error on 'objWord.ActiveDocument.Name' that no Document is Open

[image]

On Windows 7 Task Manager this is what I have. Word Application is closed but it appears there are background processes open of Word. However I close all documents I don't use so these processes shouldn't be running

[image]

Comment: What does the debugger tell you if you set a breakpoint on `If IsFileOpen` and step through the code?

Comment: To start with you need to fix your Object issues inside VBA - make sure objWord is quite and dereferenced when you exit your VBA module. It appears you're leaving a lot of Word processes open behind the scenes. Because you don't set Word visible you can't see them to close them manually, and because you don't Quit Word in your code they're left hanging around.

Comment: You have different instances of Word (which is probably because you never close the instance, only the document). `Documents` from your instance and `Documents` from these instances are different `Documents`. However your entire approach is wrong, and depending on your actual goal you need to either care about your own `Documents` only or have a look at [GetObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251785.aspx).

Comment: You need to always set the object to nothing at the end, else, strange behaviors may happen

Comment: @dbmitch When I use  objWord = Nothing and objDoc = Nothing I get error 5861 'name is a read only property' so I feel this is a separate problem

Comment: The more important one is to use `obWord.Quit` - or `objDoc.Close` but you have a syntax error - missing SET - so while a separate problem it's still a problem. Use `SET objWord = Nothing`

Answer (score 0):

I think a better test to check to see if your Word File is open is to use the actual Word Documents collection

So for your example, use something like this:

```
    With objWord
       For Each doc In .Documents 
          If doc.Name = "test.docx" Then 
              found = True 
              Exit For
          End If
       Next doc 
       If found <> True Then 
          .Documents.Open FileName:="C:/Temp/test.docx" 
       Else 
          .Documents("test.docx").Activate 
       End If
   End With
```